# Adding space between divs alters column layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a layout of 6 div tags of fixed height across 2 rows. When I add any margin around the divs, the right most div is pushed down a row. How do I counteract this?

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 frontPageCells">
              hh
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 frontPageCells">
              hh
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 frontPageCells">
              ty
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 frontPageCells">
              hh
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 frontPageCells">
              hh
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 frontPageCells">
              ty
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
CSS:
.frontPageCells{
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px; 
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Tried to offset the margin with a negative padding value but predictively this did nothing

Comment: There is no such thing as negative padding. Your cells I assume are 33% width (so 3 *33% + Xpx margin) exceeds the width of the row. I'd use padding **inside** the cells instead.

Comment: which version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: Sorry when you say inside, I did add padding but nothing changed. Can you clarify how to add on the inside please?

Comment: Version 4 of Bootstrap

Comment: ...or negative margin and `justify-content: space-between` - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ydYeJx

Comment: add `flex-nowrap` class to your row and it will stop them wrapping (if you only ever have the three per container)

Comment: use `col-3` in child and use `justify-content: space-between` in parent

Answer (score -1):

a simple hack is to add `col-12` inside your `col-4` div

```css
.frontPageCells {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="col-12  frontPageCells">
          hh
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="col-12  frontPageCells">
          hh
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="col-12  frontPageCells">
          hh
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="col-12  frontPageCells">
          hh
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="col-12  frontPageCells">
          hh
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="col-12  frontPageCells">
          hh
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```